# EnumWindows Unresolved External

Tags: c++, windows, external

I've been trying to use enumwindows to list my current windows, and have been using this code form cplusplus

```
include <iostream>
include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam);

int Main(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR pCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);

return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char class_name[80];
    char title[80];
    GetClassName(hwnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
    GetWindowText(hwnd,title,sizeof(title));
    cout <<"Window title: "<<title<<endl;
    cout <<"Class name: "<<class_name<<endl<<endl;
    return TRUE;
}
```

main() used to be winmain but I wanted to use a console application to read outputs so I switched it to main, and I get an unresolved external error when building:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   [code["int **stdcall EnumWindowsProc(struct HWND** *, long)" (?EnumWindowsProc@@YGHPAUHWND__@@J@Z) Error executing link.exe[/code]

I'm using old version of Visual C++ on XP and I have included the kernel32 lib and user32 lib, any ideas whats wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The main function is wrong. Please see [main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) for the acceptable prototypes.

Comment: After adding `#` to the includes and changing `Main` to `int main()` everything compiles and links fine. Exactly which version of VC++ are you using?

Comment: VC++ 6.0 is the current version im using